# Given three IID random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$, what is the probability that $X_1<X_2$ and $X_2>X_3$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Does the answer to this question depend on the distribution of the IID random variables? If so, what are the answers if we assume their distributions are $\bf{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ or $\textbf{Unif}(a, b)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By symmetry:

$$P(X_1>\max\{X_2,X_3\})=P(X_2>\max\{X_1,X_3\})=P(X_3>\max\{X_1,X_2\})$$

If moreover the distribution is continuous then also:$$P(X_1>\max\{X_2,X_3\})+P(X_2>\max\{X_1,X_3\})+P(X_3>\max\{X_1,X_2\})=1$$so that: $$P(X_2>\max\{X_1,X_3\})=\frac13$$

This does not work if there are elements $x\in\mathbb R$ with $P(X_1=x)>0$.

If e.g. the $X_i$ are degenerated then: $$P(X_2>\max\{X_1,X_3\})=0$$

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the probability that any of the $X_i$ are equal is $0$, there are, regardless of distribution, six equally likely orders that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ can come in:
$$
X_1<X_2<X_3\\
X_1<X_3<X_2\\
X_2<X_1<X_3\\
X_2<X_3<X_1\\
X_3<X_1<X_2\\
X_3<X_2<X_1
$$
Exactly two of these have $X_2$ as the largest, so the probability of this happening is $\frac26=\frac13$.